# Нужно модифицировать имеющийся объект

Tags: javascript

Существует объект:

```js
let obj = '[{"departure city":"Moscow","entry_id":1},{"departure city":"Spb","entry_id":2},{"departure city":"Minsk","entry_id":3},{"departure city":"Spb","entry_id":4},{"departure city":"Moscow","entry_id":5}]';
console.log(JSON.parse(obj));
```

Я стремлюсь его привести к такому виду:

```js
let obj = '[{"name":"Moscow","entries":[{"entry_id":1},{"entry_id":5}]},{"name":"Minsk","entries":[{"entry_id":3}]},{"name":"Spb","entries":[{"entry_id":2},{"entry_id":4}]}]';
console.log(JSON.parse(obj));
```

Мои попытка сделать это:

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  let cities = [];

  let city1 = new Entry("Moscow", 1);
  let city2 = new Entry("Spb", 2);
  let city3 = new Entry("Minsk", 3);
  let city4 = new Entry("Spb", 4);
  let city5 = new Entry("Moscow", 5);

  cities.push(city1, city2, city3, city4, city5);
  //console.log(cities);

  let res = cities.filter(filterByCity);
  console.log(res);

});

function Entry(city, index) {
  this["departure city"] = city;
  this.entry_id = index;
}

function filterByCity(item) {
  if (item["departure city"] === 'Spb') {
    return true;
  } else return false;
}
```

Максимум чего я добился, это вернуть массив с совпадающим городом, но дальше ступор. По идее следующий шаг это сделать `cities.filter(filterByCity)` в цикле, но тогда в функцию `filterByCity` надо как-то передавать slug города('Spb' or 'Moscow' etc.) Скорее всего что-то не то делаю. Подскажите, как можно исходный объект привести к нужному виду?

Comment: Благодарю за ответы, не знаю какой из них принять. Большая удача получить сразу несколько ответов и сравнить подходы. Как более менее разберусь с ответами обязательно приму какой-то из ответов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{
  "departure city": "Moscow",
  "entry_id": 1
}, {
  "departure city": "Spb",
  "entry_id": 2
}, {
  "departure city": "Minsk",
  "entry_id": 3
}, {
  "departure city": "Spb",
  "entry_id": 4
}, {
  "departure city": "Moscow",
  "entry_id": 5
}];

function getCityEntries(array) {
  const result = [];
  const uniqueCities = getUniqueCities(array);

  uniqueCities.forEach(item => {
    result.push({
      name: item,
      entries: array.filter(city => city["departure city"] === item).map(city => ({
        'entry_id': city.entry_id
      }))
    })
  });


  return result;
}

function getUniqueCities(array) {
  return array.map(item => item["departure city"]).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
}

console.log(getCityEntries(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "departure_city": "Moscow",
    "entry_id": 1
  },
  {
    "departure_city": "Spb",
    "entry_id": 2
  },
  {
    "departure_city": "Minsk",
    "entry_id": 3
  },
  {
    "departure_city": "Spb",
    "entry_id": 4
  },
  {
    "departure_city": "Moscow",
    "entry_id": 5
  }
]

let arr1 = arr.reduce((res,{departure_city,entry_id}) => {  
  let index = res.findIndex(el => el.name == departure_city);
  if (index != -1){
    res[index].entries.push({'entry_id':entry_id});
  } else res.push({'name':departure_city,'entries':[{'entry_id':entry_id}]})
  return res
},[])

console.log(arr1)
```